# Strange behavior with TSQL year() and month() functions

Tags: sql-server

I don't know what is going on here. The first expression in the select list produces 6 but yet the logical expression in the where clause is true.

Applies to SQL Server 2012, 2017 and 2019.

Simplified demo:

```
select
  'March 2022',
  202203-100*year(getdate())+month(getdate()),
  202203-cast(100*year(getdate())+month(getdate())as int)
where
  202203=100*year(getdate())+month(getdate())
┌──────────┬─┬─┐
│March 2022│6│0│
└──────────┴─┴─┘
```

Best Regards,

Esa

Comment: Check the [operator precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/operator-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). You simply need to use brackets: `... 202203-(100*year(getdate())+month(getdate())) ...`

Comment: Did you mean to use brackets, since multiplication happens before subtraction? What exactly are you trying to do here, because I'm pretty sure there's a less convoluted way.

Comment: This is just a demonstration of the original problem.  The goal is to produce integer YYYYYMM from current date.

Our consult uses this:

`
cast(concat(cast(year(getdate()) as char(4)),right('00'+ cast(month(getdate()) as varchar(2)),2)) as integer
`

and I would have used this:

`
100*year(getdate())+month(getdate())
`

If I put the expression in the database it is ok. But the Proof of Concept that I wanted to present our consult didn't work.

Comment: [Why not just `CONVERT(char(6), GETDATE(), 112)`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cccf0bb72bcf8c10a555c108542e89ba)? All this math is cute but what is it actually doing for you?

Comment: Sorry, I oversimplified the example. The thing is that the result must be integer like the type of the column in the table that I left out.

Comment: @lippes CONVERT(char(6), GETDATE(), 112) can be either explicitly or implicitly converted to an integer. But yes, please avoid oversimplifying.

Answer (score -1):

We all like math, sure, but why not just:

```
DECLARE @i int = CONVERT(char(6), GETDATE(), 112);
PRINT @i;
```

Result:

```
202203
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cccf0bb72bcf8c10a555c108542e89ba)

Comment: Thanks, that would produce an integer as required. The expression in real life occurs two times in a where statement so we could reuse the variable there.

CONVERT being an old school function originally from Sybase may be unfamiliar among our consults.

Comment: `CONVERT()` is just `CAST()` with more options (in particular, you can't do exactly what I've done with a single `CAST`). Also, both functions have been around since Sybase, so neither is older school than the other. If your consultants don't know what `CONVERT()` is I don't think that's `CONVERT`'s fault. :-)

Comment: I meant that CAST was introduced in SQL Server at some later stage. Don't remember exactly but I have copy of Transact-SQL Reference for version 6.0 from 1995 and there is no CAST function there.

Comment: @lippes I started with 6.5 and that was 25 years ago so I consider that to be "always" - I'll take your word for it that it wasn't there in 6.0, because I don't know for sure, but since CAST is ANSI that seems unlikely to me. In any case, my point remains: if your consultants don't know what CONVERT is in 2022, that's a problem.

Comment: Maybe the most prominent non-ANSI feature of old Microsoft TSQL was the left join *= and right join =* syntax.  It was available in SQL Server 2005 compatibility mode (90) until SQL Server 2012 came.